# I need an explanation for the Fibonacci Sequence in a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, logic, fibonacci

```
Stream.iterate(new Long[] {0L, 1L}, p -> new Long[] {p[1], p[0]+p[1]}).map(p -> p[0]);
```

Can someone explain the logic of this lambda expression to me?

I'm trying to mentally debug the Fibonacci Sequence in a lambda expression but I'm really not getting it. There's no useful reason, I really just want to understand for my own learning, I'm learning lambda expressions in college (I wrote this code by myself and I still don't understand it)

I know there are better ways to do this, but I want to understand the logic that I accidentally did and it worked

Answer (score 1):

[Stream.iterate()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) takes an initial seed (here, the long array of `{0,1}`) and a [UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html).

After setting the seed to the long array of `{0,1}`, each subsequent iterative invocation of the `UnaryOperator` creates a `new long array` using the values of the previous array as follows:

- sets *new* `p[0]` to *previous* `p[1]`.
- and  sets *new* `p[1]` to sum of *previous* `p[0]` + *previous* `p[1]`.
- it then maps to `p[0]` to get that value as the desired term

If you run the following you can see how it prints the successive creations of the array and the mapped value.

```
Stream.iterate(new Long[]{0L,1L}, p -> new Long[]{p[1],p[0] + p[1]})
       .limit(10)
       .peek(arr -> System.out.print("p="+Arrays.toString(arr) + " --> "))
       .map(p -> "p[0] = "+p[0]).forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
p=[0, 1] --> p[0] = 0
p=[1, 1] --> p[0] = 1
p=[1, 2] --> p[0] = 1
p=[2, 3] --> p[0] = 2
p=[3, 5] --> p[0] = 3
p=[5, 8] --> p[0] = 5
p=[8, 13] --> p[0] = 8
p=[13, 21] --> p[0] = 13
p=[21, 34] --> p[0] = 21
p=[34, 55] --> p[0] = 34
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream `iterate` takes 2 parameters, the seed, which is the first value and unary operator which defines how to generate the next value based on the previous one. The seed in the case is an array of two elements 0 and 1. The operator takes the second value puts in into the first place and sums the first and second to the second place, so `0, 1` -> `1, 1`, `1,1` -> `1, 2`, `1, 2` -> `2, 3` and so on. The `map` function then takes the first value from each array which results in the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Stream::iterate is a method which generates values based on the initial condition (the first parameter) and UnaryOperator (the second parameter). So to break it down:

`new Long[] {0L, 1L}` is your initial value. These are the first two elements of the fibonacci sequence. The first element emitted from the stream is this value, i.e. a list containing two elements.

`p -> new Long[] {p[1], p[0]+p[1]}` is the function which is applied to your initial value at the first iteration, then applied to the following elements on later iterations. This follows the fibonacci sequence two values at a time, which is convenient as the next element is the sum of the previous two elements.

`.map(p -> p[0])` only serves to extract the first element from the value emitted by the Stream::iterate method.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.iterate` is used to generate an infinite stream, from which you can request any number of values.
It generates the stream using two parameters, an initial seed and a generator function that uses the previous element of the stream to create the next element.

So looking at your expression:

```java
Stream.iterate(new Long[] {0L, 1L}, p -> new Long[] {p[1], p[0]+p[1]}).map(p -> p[0]);
```

The seed value, and first value emitted from this stream, is `new Long[] {0L, 1L}`, an array of the first two values of the Fibonacci sequence.

The generator function, which operates on the previous value of the stream and produces the next value, is `p -> new Long[] {p[1], p[0]+p[1]}`. This is doing the Fibonacci calculation. It takes the previous array `p` and creates a new one, where the second item in `p` becomes the new first value, and the new second value is the sum of the 2 previous values.

It is necessary to store both values because the Fibonacci sequence depends on two previous values, so the generator function needs both to be able to calculate the next value. However, it seems that the user of this stream is only interested in the next Fibonacci number, not an array of two values. Thus, the `map` call, `.map(p -> p[0])`, which is taking the stream of arrays and turning it into a stream of just a single number.

The first couple of iterations would go something like the following. When the  first value is requested from the stream, the iterator stream returns the seed, `{0, 1}`, which is then mapped to just first value of the array, so the whole stream emits `0`.

After this, we use the generator function to produce the next values. So when the second number is requested, the iterator stream calls the generator on the seed value, which results in `{1, 1}`. After `map`ping, the stream then emits `1`.

Similarly, the third number emitted is produced by calling the generator on the second value, which yields `{1, 2}`, and then `map`s to the first element, `1`.
The fourth iterated value is `{2, 3}`, `map`ping to the first element results in `2`, and so on...